# how to get wifi password from cmd with java

Tags: java, cmd

I'm trying supply my wifi connection password with java. but I have to do it as an admin.

```
try {
    Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("netsh.exe wlan show profiles name=superonline key=clear");
    BufferedReader bf = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));
    while (bf.readLine() != null)
        System.out.println(bf.readLine());
} catch (Exception ex) {
    ex.printStackTrace();
}
```

When I try it as a standard user:

[image]

When I try it as administrator:

How can do this in java code?

[image]

Comment: have you read [ask]? we are not a free coding service

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  I have fixed English issues with your post.  Please edit your post and show us your java code so far.

Comment: hi, thanks for reply, my code is here                                                              public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException, IOException {
        try {
            Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("netsh wlan show profiles name=superonline key=clear");
            BufferedReader bf =new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));
            while (bf.readLine() != null)
                System.out.println(bf.readLine());
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `java.util.Scanner` class:

```
Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("netsh wlan show profiles name=superonline key=clear"); 
Scanner sc=new Scanner(p.getInputStream());
while (sc.hasNextLine()) {
    System.out.println(sc.nextLine());
}
```

Comment: hi, thanks for reply but this is not run as administrator

Answer (score 0):

you can't get that kind of access with java.

The best you can do is wrap the output of the command into InputStream and try to read data from there

```
  public static void main(String[] args) {
   try {
   // create a new process
   System.out.println("Creating Process...");
   Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("netsh.exe wlan .......");

   // get the input stream of the process and print it
   InputStream in = p.getInputStream();
   for (int i = 0; i < in.available(); i++) {
   System.out.println("" + in.read());
   }

   // wait for 10 seconds and then destroy the process
   Thread.sleep(10000);
   p.destroy();

   } catch (Exception ex) {
   ex.printStackTrace();
   }

   }
```

Comment: thanks for reply, but it doesn't work for me. because wifi password doesn not appear in command line. because of administrator-user  i think.